# Vue components within user created content

Tags: node.js, vuejs2

I have basic setup for my website that looks like this (has to work as ssr and clients side):

**app.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
   <ui-website-header />
   <ui-website-main-menu />
   <ui-website-content />
   <ui-website-footer-menu />
  </div>
</template>
```

**ui-website-content.vue**

```
<template>
   <div v-html="content"></div>
</template>
```

The `content` was created using a wysiwyg editor like ckeditor. Right now that `content` is process before it is passed to vue.

My problem is, that `content` contains elements (like navigation elements, newsfeed, ...) that I want to be represented as vue components.

The content could look like this:

```
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
<ui-news-feed />
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
<ui-sub-menu />
```

And for `<ui-news-feed />`  and `<ui-sub-menu />`  the corresponding vue components has to be loaded.

I know that I can compile the `content` of each site `vue-template-compiler` and store the resulting `render` and `staticRenderFns` with the `content`  in the database, and create the component for that site on demand.

And register it locally:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app'
  components: {
    'content-component': ComponentComponent
  }
})
```

Is there a major downside to this approach or another way to solve that?